# Getting a substring text from a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, text, substring

Lets say I have a text `Howard Johnson, 21 (USA)`

I want to get the substring of the text `Johnson`.

I could do this with `InStr` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left` Or `Mid`, But I always found this method rather *tedious* and I want to know if there is another easier method to do this.

```
Dim myText As String = "Howard Johnson, 21 (USA)"
Dim textIWant As String = InStr(1, myText, Chr(32))
Dim LastName As String = Mid(myText, textIWant + 1, textIWant)
'Output: Johnson
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you always want to get word after first space?

Comment: @DarkKnight, nope, it's just an example. I used `InStr` to find the length where I want my text to start, in this case, it is the first space before `Johnson`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code - it uses the `IndexOf` function of a `String` to locate the first instance of a character within that `String`.

For a surname, the example code is looking for the first space and the first comma and taking the text in between. The assumption is that the surname is always delimited that way.

For the country, the example code is looking for the first ( and the last ) and taking the text in between. The assumption is that the country is always in round brackets.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Input As String
    Dim Surname As String
    Dim Country As String

    Input = "Howard Johnson, 21 (USA)"
    Surname = Input.Substring(Input.IndexOf(" ") + 1, Input.IndexOf(",") - Input.IndexOf(" ") - 1)
    Country = Input.Substring(Input.IndexOf("(") + 1, Input.IndexOf(")") - Input.IndexOf("(") - 1)

    Console.WriteLine(Surname)
    Console.WriteLine(Country)

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

It will also work for people who have spaces in their surname e.g.:

```
Input = "Albert del Rosario, 75 (Phillipines)"
Surname = Input.Substring(Input.IndexOf(" ") + 1, Input.IndexOf(",") - Input.IndexOf(" ") - 1)
```

Will output

`del Rosario`

Comment: Awesome, this works too, but what is the explanation for this code?

Comment: I see.. That's pretty informative. I'm trying to practice more on this by getting the Country of the Input for now... But I'm still not getting it...

       `Input = "Howard Johnson, 21 (USA)"
        Country = Input.Substring(Input.IndexOf("(") + 1)`

I'm getting "USA)"

Comment: You are missing a check for the closing bracket e.g. `IndexOf(")")` - see the  update in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myText = "Howard Johnson, 21 (USA)"
Dim LastName = myText.Split(" "c, ","c)(1)  ' myText.Split(" "c, ","c) gives array {"Howard", "Johnson", "", "21", "(USA)"}
```